# MicroDEM changes the aspect ratio of DEM

Tags: dem

I downloaded a DEM from Open Topography (SRTM) and opened it in MicroDEM which changed the aspect ratio. The original DEM was 2329 px * 1679 px but that in MicroDEM when it was saved on disk was 2329 px * 2134 px. No clipping happened and it just changed the aspect ratio. Why is that?

Comment: it may have reprojected on import. the reprojection may have triggered some interpolation of "new" pixels